# UITableView not scrolling to bottom every time when using animations

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, animation

I have an UITableView where I add new rows dynamically during the execution of the program. I always add new rows to the bottom and when that happens I want the table view to scroll to the bottom and show the new rows.

```
NSInteger oldCount = [self.game count];
dispatch_async( dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
    //This may take a long time
    BOOL gameStateChanged = [self.game update] ;
    dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if (gameStateChanged)
        {
            NSMutableArray* ipaths = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:5];
            NSInteger newCount = [self.game count];
            for (NSInteger i = oldCount; i < newCount; i++)
            {
                [ipaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
            }
            NSIndexPath* ipath = [ipaths lastObject];
            [self.wordsTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:ipaths 
                                       withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
            [self.wordsTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath: ipath 
                                       atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom 
                                               animated:YES];
        }
    });
});
```

The problem is that it stops scrolling at sometimes. After it has stopped scrolling it does not start scrolling by itself at subsequent calls to the same method unless the user scrolls  the table view manually.

If I turn off animations for the scrolling, sending `animated:NO`, it works perfectly. How can this be? And how can I make it work using animations?

Answer (score 0):

Try waiting till done when calling the method… another possibility would be integrating the animated:no function in an animation block…

Something like that:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];

[self.wordsTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath: ipath 
                                       atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom 
                                               animated:NO];

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

This is not really the nicest solution but maybe that helps…

Comment: By waiting, do you mean not starting two animations at the same time? I try to read up on this way of doing animations an it says that it is discouraged as of iOS 4.0. I don't really want to create my own animation as there is it is built in into UITableView.